# Jenkins only executes first line of groovy closure

Tags: jenkins, groovy, closures

I have the following two Classes which work just fine locally in groovy, but once I use them with Jenkins Shared Libraries I run into some issues.

./Template.groovy

```
class Template {
    String arch
    String type
    def body = {}

    Template(type, arch, body) {
        this.arch = arch
        this.type = type
        this.body = body
    }
}
```

./TemplateBook.groovy

```
import Template

class TemplateBook {
    def templates = []

    TemplateBook() {
        def template = new Template("test", "lnx", { args -> sh('echo "Hello World!"'); sh("echo Test"); sh("echo $args")})
        templates.push(template)
    }

    def getTemplate(type, arch) {
        def template
        for (def i = 0; i < templates.size(); i++) {
            if (templates[i].arch == arch && templates[i].type == type) {
                template = templates[i].getBody()
                i = templates.size()
            }
        }
        return template
    }
}
```

Using the `Template.body` directly works just fine (locally and on Jenkins), but using the `TemplateBook.getTemplate()` only executes the first line of the closure (body).

```
def templateBook = new TemplateBook()
def body = templateBook.getTemplate("test", "lnx")

body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
body.delegate = this
body("test")
```

Output:
Hello World!

```
def template = new Template("type", "arch", { args -> sh('echo "Hello World!"'); sh("echo Test"); sh("echo $args")})

def body2 = template.body
body2.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
body2.delegate = this
body2("test")
```

Output:
Hello World!
Test
test

Comment: Have you found a solution for that? I have a similar issue. Maybe it has something with CPS used by Jenkins?

Comment: Sadly I have not. It most likely has to with the Jenkins CPS. And i feel like it also has to do with the array the closure is stored in. My current solution is hard coding the closure in if(){}else{} statements.